# How to get svm and naive-bayes classification accuracy and confusion matrix from csv UTF-8 (comma delimited) in python

Tags: python, classification, svm, naivebayes, confusion-matrix

Training data: csv
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMtKP.png)

Prediction data: csv 
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eb0pi.png)

I need to produce accuracy and confusion matrix of svm and naive-bayes classification in python.

Thanks in advance.